# centralizar botao messenger facebook

Tags: html, css, facebook

Não estou conseguindo centralizar o botão do facebook de forma nenhuma!
Se alguém puder me auxiliar, agradeço!

Segue HTML do que tentei fazer:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div style="margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    width: 6em !important;" class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="283210402013309"
  theme_color="#0084ff"
  logged_in_greeting="Oi! Deixe sua mensagem!"
  logged_out_greeting="Oi! Deixe sua mensagem!"
  center_align="true">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.3'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Imagem da forma que eu quero que fique:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas alinhar o que onde? Vc que alinhar a div `<div id="fb-root"></div>` na horizontal no centro da página? Ou na vertical no meio da página? De mais detalhes

Comment: Eu gostaria que fosse ao centro da página, mas se for possível. Centralizar no canto inferior esquerdo da página.

Comment: Cara tá difícil de entender o que vc escreveu... centralizar na esquerda? ou está no canto esquerdo ou está no centro da página...

Comment: Desculpe a a forma que eu expliquei. Editei o post, queria que ficasse daquela forma que o botão do whats está.

Comment: Pq não usa positivo fixed?

Comment: position: fixed; O botão nem se mexe. Assim como eu fiz acima

Answer (score -1):

Tenta assim

```
style="display: block !important; margin-left: auto !important; margin-right: auto !important; width: 6em !important;"
```